# Change the location of a barplot legend

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend

My legend is overlapping my barplot - (stackoverflow will not let me post an image)

I have searched through a few similar questions but have not been able to resolve my problem. May I add that I am very new to R. I would be very grateful if anyone could help.

Here is my script

```
mids<-barplot(mean.growth,beside=T,legend=T, ylim=c(0,0.01), ylab="Growth (mm)")
arrows(mids,mean.growth-se.growth,mids,mean.growth+se.growth,length=0.1, code=3, angle=90)

text(mids,mean.growth+0.003,labels=c("bc","a","b","cd","bc","bcd","cd","d","cd","d","d","cd"))
```

Comment: Some sample data in the same range might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you read `?barplot`, you'll see that you can supply a list of arguments to be passed on to 'legend()'.   The obvious suggestions are to set the x parameter, as in:

```
barplot(mean.growth,
        beside=T,
        legend=T, 
        args.legend = list(x = 'topleft') # or 'top','bottom','left','right',etc.
        ylim=c(0,0.01), 
        ylab="Growth (mm)")
```

or to expand the `xlim` or `ylim` parameters to make the room for the legend.